# APIKey Android Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, api-key

I'am using Android Studio right now, and I decied to make an app that use Google Map API.

My app is very simple, I have a AutoCompleteTextView. Everytime I write something in AutoCompleteTextView, it will automatic suggest some location that is the same with the name I text.

I follow how to get the api key of google, and I did exactly. But when I text, it not suggest anything.

I thought my code is wrong, but when I change my Api key by another api key of someone I took in the internet. It worked fine.

Please tell me why ?

Sorry about my English, it is not native.

Comment: If a seperate key worked and yours did not it could just be that you hadn't setup the key properly in the developer api options.  Generally one thing I've noticed is that browser api keys tend to work easier.

Comment: Can you give me a key and I will test it.
I don't know why my api key cannot to used. Google still recognized everytime I used my app and sent request to google. But I didn't send the suggest I want

Answer (score 0):

This problem are solved.

Just because I forgot create API by browser